# How to get counter_cache / invitations_count working for devise invitable Rails gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, devise-invitable

I'm using devise invitable in my Rails app. The invitations_count column (which is supposed to be the counter cache for invitations sent) stays at nil.

initializers/devise.rb

```
# The column name used for counter_cache column. If this is nil,
# the #invited_by association is declared without counter_cache.
# Default: nil
config.invited_by_counter_cache = :invitations_count
```

The above is how the gem arrives. I've uncommented the last line to enable the counter.

I've read the devise invitable Github issues page, searched SO and Google, and tried fiddling in various places in my app. The rest of the gem is working just fine and sending invitations but no counter.

Ideas on how to fix? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it was your problem but personally I hadn't get right this feature. This column save the number of invitation someone sent, not the number of invitation someone received.

You have to pass a second argument to the #invite! method to trigger the counter cache on the record who invited.

[Link to the test](https://github.com/scambra/devise_invitable/blob/4f211cbf80a7690a7ddffe05adb59a0a4012c0f1/test/models/invitable_test.rb)